# How to make a list from DataFrame?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame (coordinates):

```
    X   Y   Z
0  11  44  77
1  22  55  88
2  33  66  99
```

I need to get Y and Z columns values to a list.
If I do something like:

```
centers = [df['Y'], df['Z']]
```

or

```
Y = [df['Y']]
```

I got a list with index columns like:

```
print Y

    0  44
    1  55
    2  66
```

How to create a list without indexes values (0,1,2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather try filtering on the wanted columns, taking the values and convert them to a list:

```
df[['Y','Z']].T.values.tolist()

#[[44L, 55L, 66L], [77L, 88L, 99L]]
```

If you want a list row by row:

```
df[['Y','Z']].values.tolist()

#[[44L, 77L], [55L, 88L], [66L, 99L]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I convert this list to
`[[44, 77], [55, 88], [66, 99]]`
?

Comment: without the transposition T